# Displaying same image multiple times at different locations in a web page using JavaScript or CSS

Tags: java, css, image

I’m looking to create a web page with 6 coupons on it, two per line in a web space of 1275 X 1650. Each coupon space will consist of a different image. The problem is I will be creating 20 such web pages that will have these coupons on them. Now some of the same images will appear in different locations/positions on the various web pages. Is there a way to update the same image that appear in different locations/positions at the same time?  And what language is used to complete this? I’ve tried CSS but it don’t think it’s possible. So should I be using JavaScript.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to update the pages on your web server, or in a client browser?  If in the client, do they have multiple pages open (if not, then there aren't any repeated images)?  Please be more specific as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Why do you have a "Java" tag? JavaScript is NOT Java.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem completely but I'll give it a shot.

Let's say you have your 6 coupons defined as classes in your CSS: `.coupon1` `.coupon2` `.coupon3` `.coupon4` `.coupon5` `.coupon6`

Then, you will just need to update a given class (note that a class can be used many times in the same page) to update all coupons with this class.

You will need to use `background` css property to define how the coupon will look like.